Ghost Ship horror movie [not Ghost Ship (2002) or Death Ship (1980)]
I am looking for a ghost ship movie I saw a few years back, and it is not Ghost ship (2002) or Death Ship (1980) -- I already watched them in the last few days on my search for this movie, which I have seen, I think, 5-10 years back.
The story is very close to Ghost Ship (2002) though: A crew discovers a large, abandoned metal ship. For some reason, they stay overnight on the ship. I remember there being plenty of skeletons on the beds. Somehow everyone died on that ship, but they were well-preserved (gas? salt? some poison?). I remember the ghosts of the skeletons illustrated in green. Everything was pretty darkly shot. Save to say it is a horror-movie. It was produced after 1980, but I think before ~2005.
And it did not have Nazis. 
It is also possible it was a direct-to-TV production, or an episode of some paranormal series.
If you could help me find this movie again, I would really appreciate it!

A similar plot in the 1995 X files episode Dod Kalm:

Mulder and Scully are called in when a boatload of survivors from a U.S. Navy destroyer are found. What particularly catches Agent Mulder's attention is that all of these sailors appear to have aged many decades in the course of a few days. Mulder and Scully travel to Norway where they find a civilian fisherman who is willing to take them to the destroyer's last known position.

They reach the abandoned ship and investigate it in the dark, eventually finding the mummified remains of crew members in their beds. Turns out they died after aging rapidly, and pretty soon this also happens to Mulder and Scully.

This is the movie I saw with the ghost pirates... The Ghost Galleon (1974)
Trailer here:



Not nearly as scary as I remember...
